# Numpy 2-D array changing values everytime I execute the code

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, google-colaboratory

I'm using python and numpy to manually solve some power systems problems, one problem I've got is to swap columns and rows. But everytime I execute the code, it comes with different values in different positions.

This is my code:

```
 Y = 
         0.00-10.00j        -0.00+10.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j
        -0.00+10.00j        24.63-71.51j        -8.21+20.52j       -16.42+41.04j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j
          0.00+0.00j        -8.21+20.52j        24.63-69.51j          0.00+0.00j         -0.00+8.00j          0.00+0.00j
          0.00+0.00j       -16.42+41.04j          0.00+0.00j        24.63-61.51j        -8.21+20.52j          0.00+0.00j
          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j         -0.00+8.00j        -8.21+20.52j        24.63-61.51j          0.00+0.00j
          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00-8.00j
```

```
Ya = np.copy(Y) # Y is the 2D array above
print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:20.2f}'.format(item) for item in row]) 
      for row in Ya]))
print('\n')
Ya[[1, 3]] = Ya[[3, 1]]
Ya[[2, 4]] = Ya[[4, 2]]
Ya[[3, 4]] = Ya[[4, 3]]
Ya[[3, 5]] = Ya[[5, 3]]

Ya[: ,[1, 3]] = Ya[:, [3, 1]]
Ya[:, [2, 4]] = Ya[:, [4, 2]]
Ya[:, [3, 4]] = Ya[:, [4, 3]]
Ya[:, [3, 5]] = Ya[:, [5, 3]]

print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:20.2f}'.format(item) for item in row]) 
      for row in np.array(Ya)]))
print('\n')

# Reduced Matrix
temp1 = np.copy(Ya[0:4, 0:4])
temp2 = np.copy(Ya[0:4, 4:])
temp3 = np.copy(Ya[4:, 0:4])
temp4 = np.copy(Ya[4:, 4:])

Y_r = temp1 - (temp2 * (np.matrix(temp4).getI()) * temp3)
print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:20.2f}'.format(item) for item in row]) 
      for row in np.array(Y_r)]))
```

As you can see, I'm printing Ya several times just to check if everything is going right and it is. But even in the first Ya print, it changes the values everytime I run the code.

I don't know if it can be related to this, but I'm running it on Google Colab. The first line in the code above is in a different cell than the rest of the code, where I create Y.

Comment: Print `Y` on the first line before doing anything else. Without seeing any other code, it's impossible to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @MadPhysicist done

Comment: Can you show the suspect output?

Comment: I see print statements, but no results.  I can't see your screen from here!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting different values every time you execute, I think it must be something to do with your environment. I copied your code and made some slight changes just to test and every time I run it, I get the same output:

```py
import numpy as np

Y = np.array([[0.00-10.00j, -0.00+10.00j, 0.00+0.00j, 0.00+0.00j, 0.00+0.00j, 0.00+0.00j],
              [-0.00+10.00j, 24.63-71.51j, -8.21+20.52j, -16.42+41.04j, 0.00+0.00j, 0.00+0.00j],
              [0.00+0.00j, -8.21+20.52j, 24.63-69.51j, 0.00+0.00j, -0.00+8.00j, 0.00+0.00j],
              [0.00+0.00j, -16.42+41.04j, 0.00+0.00j, 24.63-61.51j, -8.21+20.52j, 0.00+0.00j],
              [0.00+0.00j, 0.00+0.00j, -0.00+8.00j, -8.21+20.52j, 24.63-61.51j, 0.00+0.00j],
              [0.00+0.00j, 0.00+0.00j, 0.00+0.00j, 0.00+0.00j, 0.00+0.00j, 0.00-8.00j]])

Ya = np.copy(Y)
def print_mat(mat):
    print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:20.2f}'.format(item) for item in row]) for row in mat]))

print_mat(Ya)
print('\n')
Ya[[1, 3]] = Ya[[3, 1]]
Ya[[2, 4]] = Ya[[4, 2]]
Ya[[3, 4]] = Ya[[4, 3]]
Ya[[3, 5]] = Ya[[5, 3]]

print_mat(Ya)
```

Always gives me this output:

```
         0.00-10.00j         0.00+10.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j
         0.00+10.00j        24.63-71.51j        -8.21+20.52j       -16.42+41.04j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j
          0.00+0.00j        -8.21+20.52j        24.63-69.51j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+8.00j          0.00+0.00j
          0.00+0.00j       -16.42+41.04j          0.00+0.00j        24.63-61.51j        -8.21+20.52j          0.00+0.00j
          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+8.00j        -8.21+20.52j        24.63-61.51j          0.00+0.00j
          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00-8.00j


         0.00-10.00j         0.00+10.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j
          0.00+0.00j       -16.42+41.04j          0.00+0.00j        24.63-61.51j        -8.21+20.52j          0.00+0.00j
          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+8.00j        -8.21+20.52j        24.63-61.51j          0.00+0.00j
          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j          0.00-8.00j
         0.00+10.00j        24.63-71.51j        -8.21+20.52j       -16.42+41.04j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+0.00j
          0.00+0.00j        -8.21+20.52j        24.63-69.51j          0.00+0.00j          0.00+8.00j          0.00+0.00j
```

I don't see any other statements in the rest of your code that should not run the same way every time. I would recommend trying to run in an environment you have more control over if at all possible.

Comment: Yes, it's probably a problem from Google Colab, I think it saves the values from the last executed code, even if it's in the same cell.
I tried it in other environment and it worked. Thanks for your help.